# Getting XPath attributes with Scrapy

Tags: python, xml, xpath, namespaces, scrapy

I am parsing an XML document with Scrapy and having trouble with the XPaths.

My XML looks like this:

```
<sdn:screen>
 <foaf:Image rdf:about="http://search.shinrokuden.irides.tohoku.ac.jp/shinrokuden/archive/screen/07f9d1a0-5ef4-11e2-91ca-000c2923bf22.jpg"/>
</sdn:screen>
```

I need the url following `rdf:about=`. I am using scrapy's `remove_namespaces()` feature, so that I don't need to use namespaces in my XPath. I have tried the following XPaths but they all return `[]`:

```
xxs.select('//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen/Image/about').extract()

xxs.select('//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen/Image/@about').extract()

xxs.select('//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen/Image[@about]').extract()

xxs.select('//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen[@about]').extract()

xxs.select('//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen/@about').extract()
```

And many other similar variations.

I know that the path up to `'//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen/Image'` is correct because that outputs data, but like I said, the ones about that try to access the "rdf:about" section all come up with `[]`. I really don't think namespaces are an issue, since I removed the namespaces, but again I could be wrong.

Comment: Where are those namespaces declared?

Comment: you might want to get rid of the `record/metadata/RDF/Resource` business and try to simplify the problem set as much as possible, also you could show the creation of `xxs`

Comment: It seems to me `.remove_namespaces()` does not remove namespaces for element attributes. `self._root.iter(*)` (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/selector/lxmlsel.py#L76) iters only on elements, not on attributes. I tested with https://itunes.apple.com/fr/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/xml and had to call `xxs.register_namespace("im", "http://itunes.apple.com/rss")` to access `xxs.select('//entry//@im:assetType')`

Comment: @TheCorinne, I opened an issue and proposed a fix for it at https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/416

Comment: @pault. Thank you so much! I know this is a super delayed response, but you really helped me out. And thanks for fixing it on scrapy too - you're awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for the XPath to the attribute:

```
//record/metadata/RDF/Resource/screen/Image/attribute::rdf:about
```

I haven't tested it but something similar will pull the attribute

you can read more about xpath at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp